# Using a modified PDFTron Tools Framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods, pdftron, pdfnet

I'm working on a iOS Framework (using CocoaPods) that, as of today, uses PDFNet.framework as its only dependency.

Everything works as expected when I use the resulting framework in another "top level" project.

Now I'm trying to make this same Framework use the Tools.framework, as I intend to use the annotations from the Tools library.

Is there a common approach in doing so?

I've tried building the Tools source code but it fails as the dependency  isn't found.

Comment: "but it fails as the dependency isn't found" could you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need should be in the following guide.
https://blog.pdftron.com/2016/11/14/getting-started-with-pdfnet-for-ios/

If that guide does not help, then please answer my comment above.